# Why does SQL Server say it can't convert varchar to numeric?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, varchar

I have the following schema/data in MSSQL Server 2019 ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb7ae/3)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE products(
    idn NUMERIC(9) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE sales(
    idn NUMERIC(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    pid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products (idn) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO sales (idn, pid, type) VALUES (1, 1, 'number');
INSERT INTO sales (idn, pid, type) VALUES (2, 'Colgate', 'word');
```

`sales` has mixed data i.e `VARCHAR` and `NUMERIC`. The transaction filter takes care of `JOIN`ing correctly.

Why does the following `SELECT` fail (For some [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936620/why-does-my-query-break-when-it-is-parameterized) beyond my control, the generated query has `N` literals for strings.)?

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid 
    AND sales.type = N'number' 
WHERE 
    products.idn in (1);
```

I don't see why casting `NVARCHAR` to `NUMERIC` is an issue:

```sql
SELECT CAST (N'1' as NUMERIC);
```

If I modify the query slightly it works:

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid 
    AND sales.type = N 'number' 
WHERE
    -- Selecting the same data from `sales`.
    sales.pid in (1);

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid
    -- Dropping the `N` prefix.
    AND sales.type = 'number' 
WHERE 
    products.idn in (1);
```

Comment: `sales.pid` is not NVARCHAR, it it VARCHAR. 1-Insert VARCHAR values using single quotes: `INSERT INTO sales (idn, pid, type) VALUES (1, '1', 'number');`.  2: Remove `N` in you ON clause. Comparing different data types can produce this error.

Comment: Thanks @McNets. 1 is producing the same error, though yeah, the insert should be like that. 2 is beyond my control which is the biggest problem (bind-params are coming from PyODBC). I can't see why it fails because I am able to `CAST` just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conversion error will occur at run time when an attempt is made to convert the `sales.pid` value 'Colgate' value to numeric(9) to evaluate the join criteria. As to whether or not this actually happens depends on the order of evaluation in the execution plan.

Below is the sales table clustered index scan predicate from the [Unicode literal execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1x9nSYsL), showing the conversion occurs before the 'number' condition is evaluated:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(9,0),[tempdb].[dbo].[sales].[pid],0)=(1.) AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(10),[tempdb].[dbo].[sales].[type],0)=N'number'
```

The [plan with the non-Unicode literal](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy8AnHti8) has the same shape except the predicate order in the scan operator is reversed:

```
[tempdb].[dbo].[sales].[type]='number' AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(9,0),[tempdb].[dbo].[sales].[pid],0)=(1.)
```

Although the non-Unicode literal (or parameter) may workaround the problem, the query will still be vulnerable to run time errors. This can be addressed with `TRY_CAST`, `TRY_CONVERT`, `CASE` expression, etc. but it would be better to fix the data model such as to ensure only like or compatible data types are compared.

Comment: Is there any reason why it is reversed? I would have expected it to behave the same way for `N''` and `'`' - it would have led us to re-design much earlier :) Just curious.

Comment: I can only speculate but I suspect SQL Server evaluates the expression that doesn't require conversion first since it's less costly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a column that contains text values (pid) to join on a numeric column

```
INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid
```

When you do a join of those 2 tables, SQL needs to compare all the rows from idn to all the rows from pid. In order to compare them, it needs to convert you varchar into numeric.

How can SQL convert 'Colgate' into a number ? this is why it fails.

You should read about database normalization.

Your PID column does not seems good and you would probably need another table with a product ID and a product description (where 'Colgate' will be the description) in order to have it works as you are expecting.

Comment: Yeah I do understand it is mixed data which is not good, but it does work when you have an extra filter that says `entity_type = 'number'` - did you see that?

Comment: M. Smith explained why this extra filter may not always work

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following SELECT fail (For some reason beyond my control, the generated query has N literals for strings.)?

Because it's getting an execution plan that evaluates

```
sales.pid=1
```

for the row with

```
sales.pid = 'Colgate'
```

before it evaluates the predicate

```
sales.type = N'Number'
```

`int` has a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than `varchar` so to perform the comparison the 'varchar' is implicitly converted to `int`.  This conversion fails for "Colgate".

The way to lock the order of evaluation for those two conditions is with a CASE expression.  EG

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales 
    ON  case when sales.type = N'number' and sales.pid = products.idn then 1 else 0 end = 1
WHERE 
products.idn = 1
```

That might cause performance issues at scale, but that's one of the many reasons each column should have only one type of data in it.

Comment: Apart from performance issues, using CASE, to lock the order, is a nice idea ... I was thinking about the possibility of fixing the order at some point ... Thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 1):

The query optimizer might change the order things are done to get your result the fastest way among the options it come up with (given the result of the query isn't altered).

Knowing that, ff you check the execution plan it will help you understand the reason you get the error with one query and not with the other given the sample data you provided:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid
    -- Dropping the `N` prefix.
    AND sales.type = 'number' 
WHERE 
    products.idn in (1);
```

[Query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJH4fSYs8)

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN sales ON products.idn = sales.pid 
    AND sales.type = N'number' 
WHERE 
    products.idn in (1);
```

[Query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyFlNSFjI)

[image: Predicate of query plan]

**Query 1** worked because when you removed the N (which is used to convert a string to `nvarchar`) SQL Server didn't need to perform an implicit convertion of `sales.type` from varchar to nvarchar. In this case `sales.pid` has an implicit convertion on both queries since it's being compared to `products.idn` which has a different data type. The query optimizer decides the comparison of a column without a implicit convertion is less expensive, so it starts by executing the predicate `sales.type = 'number'` and it generates a subset composed of the rows which contains all the values of `sales.type` as numbers (and you can convert real numbers from a string cloumn with no problem). Thus the query works.

**Query 2** throws an error because both predicates from `sales` have implicit convertions and to optimizer chose to begin from `sales.pid` before filtering only the rows that keep numbers. When it tries to convert the value `'Colgate'` to a `numeric(9,0)` data type, you get the error.